# Correct spelling of names, Chebyshev and Cholesky

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview

I'm writing a paper on orthogonal polynomials and I have to cite results by Chebyshev and Cholesky. I found several and different transliterations from Russian. I wonder if there is a standard and accepted way to spell them. Thanks

Comment: Why not ask Wikipedia? Cholesky was not a Russian, as far as I know.

Comment: Of course I looked up Wikipedia, but I found on other sources (books, papers...) other spellings. So the question is what is more accepted, is there a rule?

Comment: Cholesky is French with Polish heritage. Given that he spelled his name _in French_ as written here, you shouldn't change it to anything else.

Comment: Transliteration is a complicated topic and may lack standardization. For example, Mandarin has pinyin and Wade-Giles, while Cantonese has several of its own systems. If an author has published in an English-language journal at least once, then I would use whatever spelling that author chose.

Comment: The current standard transliteration of Чебышёв is, in English, Chebyshev, in French, Tchebychev. At least for the 1st and 3rd consonants, there's no ambiguity, although "Chebychev" is a frequent (incoherent) error and most French mathematicians/teachers mispronounce the third consonant as "tch" instead of "sh". According to Zentrallblatt, he published with as many spellings as: *Chebyshev* (English), *Tchebichef, Tchebycheff, Tchebycheff,Tchébycheff, Tchébycheff* (French), *Tschebychew, Tschebyscheff, Tschebyscheff, Tschebyschew, Tschebyschew,* (German) *Čebišev* (?).

Comment: @BenCrowell, isn't it more likely that the spelling in a journal was chosen by the journal than by the author?  (Having only published in English-language journals, I don't know; it's a genuine question.)

Comment: (I was also beaten to the point by @YCor that it's possible that an author published, Shakespeare-like, under many different spellings of his or her name.)

Comment: For the confusion of sounds by some French, I think the English words like "chewing-gum" are to blame. No as much as our national arrogance with regard to other languages than ours though.

Comment: There's also an issue about the last vowel in Chebyshev's name, since Russian "ë" ought to rather be transliterated into something akin to "yo" (and German Wikipedia spells it as "Tschebyschow", Spanish Wikipedia as "Chebyshov"): the use by Chebyshev of these various spellings leave little doubt that, when pronouncing his own name in French, English or German, he pronounced the last  syllabic as "shef" and not "shof".

Comment: Native Russian speakers habitually mispronounce the name. The catch is that "ë" is always stressed in Russian, however many people (me including) would put the stress on the 1st "e".

Comment: The list I copied from Math Zentrallblatt is not injective (it was injective before I erased initial of first name), so let me copy the correct list:  *Chebyshev* (English), *Tchebichef, Tchebycheff, Tchébycheff*, (French), *Tschebychew, Tschebyscheff*  (German) Čebišev (ISO 9).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get access to the scan of original review (as was available on the previous version of MZb) and MZb plainly uniformized to "Chebyshev" without mentioning the name as written in the journal; the only papers I could access are in French journals where each of *Tchebicheff* (1844, 1884, 1884) *Tchebichef* (1846) "Tchebichev" (1857), *Tchébycheff* (1868) *Tchébichef* (1898). Note that these are 5 of the 12 elements of the set Tch$\{$e,é$\}$b$\{i,y\}$che$\{$f,ff,v$\}$, and doesn't include the currently used French one Tchebychev.

Comment: The only Russian publication I found is dated 1946 (he was dead for more than 50 years) http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=7034&option_lang=eng, *on the cutting of garments*, and he's written Чебышeв and not Чебышёв. It refers to something related to "*Association française pour l'avancement des sciences*" in 1878 but I guess it was typed around 1946 since the year 1936 is mentioned in a footnote p1. So it would be useful if anybody has access to how Chebyshev wrote his name in Russian in publications while alive.

Comment: Also, until 1898, MZb lists 24 articles by Chebyshev: 15 in French, 7 in Russian, 1 in Italian, 1 in German. The one in Italian is a translation of that in German (*Theorie der Congruenzen*, named *Tschebyscheff*), which itself refers to a translation but it's unclear to me whether the Russian original was published.

Comment: Philip J. Davis wrote a **book** about how to spell Chebyshev. In the words of Wikipedia: "His best-known book outside the field of mathematics is *The Thread: A Mathematical Yarn* (1983, 2nd ed. 1989), which "has raised Digression into a literary form" (Gerard Piel); it takes off from the name of the Russian mathematician Tschebyscheff, and in the course of explaining why he insists on that "barbaric, Teutonic, non-standard orthography" (in the words of a reader of *Interpolation and Approximation* who wrote him to complain) he digresses in many amusing directions."

Comment: @YCor, in Russian printed texts, ё is customarily not used and replaced by е (well this used to make typesetting cheaper; it's a contentious point now, there are activists who advocate that ё should always be used). And if someone's name is spelled in their passport with е, it may be considered *incorrect* to spell it elsewhere with ё, even if ё is clearly implied. In our case, it's unclear even to a native speaker how to pronounce it; I heard Chebyshev used prononciation with ё, but I have no source.

Comment: In fact, Chebotarev/Chebotaryov is a similar case, but it's somewhat easier in that any native speaker would pronounce "Chebotaryov" there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here](http://www.forvo.com/word/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2/) you can hear the pronounce by a Russian speaking person.

As to the romanization, which usually does have a standard form in any language, I'd use the one of the language you are writing in your paper. In English it is [Chebyshev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pafnuty_Chebyshev) (not Cheby_ch_ev). You can see the corresponding versions switching to other languages  from the linked article in en.wikipedia (list of languages on the left).

Comment: I think this can be a good motivation for the choice 'Chebyshev', I wish to thank also all the other users for their constructive comments.

Comment: Cheybshev is better than Chebychev (in my view) also because the latter form transliterates two different consonant sounds to the same letter combination /ch/.

Answer (score 6):

According to [ISO 9](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=3589) (see also [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9)), Чебышëв must be spelled Čebyšëv.  Sometimes this spelling is used, cf. [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%C4%8Ceby%C5%A1%C3%ABv).

Comment: Actually many countries adopt the International Standard for transliterating  Slavic names, e.g. Italy, at least since the '70s, and "Čebyšëv" is customary in Italian maths texts. In English, the traditional form "Chebyshev" is preferred.

Comment: The letters Č, š, and ë don't belong to English, so that is not the practical way to spell it for a paper in English. Similarly, Chebotarev is far more common in the literature than the more accurate Chebotaryov. I've never seen the name with the ending -yov in a math book citing his famous density theorem.

Comment: Well, I can only say that English can't be a model example of "how to spell". It's more of "how to spell so that no-one without insider info will be able to pronounce correctly". :–)

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: http://www.adme.ru/vdohnovenie-919705/90-anglogovoryaschih-ne-mogut-prochitat-eto-stihotvorenie-691755/

Comment: @KConrad: as I used to speak reasonably good Dutch, I don't think I can be scared by phonetics any more. :-)

Comment: @KConrad, but surely you would speak of, for example, Čech cohomology rather than Cech cohomology, despite 'Č' not "belong"ing to English?

Comment: @LSpice : I guess few people would check this out  : -)

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN, it got bumped to the front page (I guess by [YCor's edit](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/167849/2) which, amusingly, "fixed Chebyshev's spelling"!), so maybe some folks will.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the Cyrillic script? That is the canonical way of writing I would guess. (Leaving aside that Cholesky was French; his parents moved from Poland to France, according to wiki.)

All transcriptions are non-canonical, but equivalent up to (canonical?) isomorphism.

To quote wiki on Чебышёв:

> Pafnuty Lvovich Chebyshev (Russian: Пафну́тий Льво́вич Чебышёв, IPA: [pɐf'n̪utʲɪ(j) 'lʲvovʲɪt͡ɕ t͡ɕɪbɨ'ʂof]) (May 16 [O.S. May 4] 1821 – December 8 [O.S. November 26] 1894)[1] was a Russian mathematician. His name can be alternatively transliterated as Chebychev, Chebysheff, Chebyshov, Tchebychev or Tchebycheff, or Tschebyschev or Tschebyscheff (the latter two pairs are French and German transcriptions).

---

Finally, using non-roman script in LaTeX is not so hard anymore, these days.

Comment: Well, the English wiki writes 'Chebyshev', which does not appear in your list, and somewhere I found also a 'Cholewsky'.  It seems that there is not a conclusive answer. I will use 'Chebychev' and 'Cholesky'. Thanks.

Comment: @Marco, it's the third word of the shaded area.

Comment: Indeed, the name *Cholesky* is a mutation of a Polish family name *Cholewski*, so the correct spelling of *Cholesky* is *Cholesky* :-)

Comment: there can't be any conclusive answer, as for different languages using Latin alphabet you get different spelling. In different times in Russia/USSR different rules regarding transliteration were in place; it used to be German, French, English (presently). Then there is a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9 which stipulates the transliteration "Čebyšëv".

Comment: Assuming a somehwat typical context (paper in English and so on) it would make  omprehending who is referred to for the typical reader considerably more difficult if *only* a version in Cyrilic was given.  This is especially relevant in this case were the name is extremely well known.  If one then adds a transliteration the problem persists. Thus this answer does in my opinin not make a useful suggestion, which is why I downvoted it. (And on the final phrase, the point of transliteration is really not only or even mainly ease of typesetting.)

Comment: @Marco: in English the letter combination sh is much better than ch to reflect the pronunciation of the name. The letters ch reflect the right sound in *French*, but not in English. I think Chebyshev is a better choice.

Comment: @jmc: how could the Cyrillic script be more canonical when the paper is written in English? Chinese and Japanese mathematician names aren't written in Chinese or Japanese when a paper is in English.

Comment: @KConrad, perhaps they should be?

Comment: Speaking of 张's theorem for the bounded prime gaps would have had less impact though.

Comment: The claim on Wikipedia "can be alternatively transliterated as *Chebychev*..." is plainly false and has unfortunately survived since it was mistakenly added on 2006, August 13. There are many transliteration mechanism depending on target language and time but they have a certain coherence and all map the two Russian letters (Ч,ш) to distinct ones, reflecting the way to pronounce them, when it exists, which is the case in French (tch,ch), English (ch,sh), German (tsch,sch); in ISO 9 it's (č,š).

Comment: "Cholesky was French; his parents moved from Poland to France...." Maybe makes no difference to this discussion, but there was no country called Poland at the time. Pieces of Poland had been incorporated into Russia, Germany, and Austria-Hungary at the time. How Cholesky's parents would have spelled the name might depend on which piece they came from.